# JavaFX – How many characters in one row of a TextArea?

Tags: textarea, width, javafx, character, column-count

How does one calculate the number of visible characters in one row (without horizontal scrolling!) of a `TextArea` in JavaFX depending on the width of the area?
I use a monospaced font, so all chars have the same width. Is it possible to calculate the width of a font char by its font size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to calculate them.
Even with a custom font.
You can use the FontMetrics class.

```
Font font = Font.font("YourFont", 14);
FontMetrics fontMetrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(font);
double length = fontMetrics.computeStringWidth("The text ");
```

But I guess this is the wrong direction?

But if your font is monospaced you can compute the width of one character and
then just simply divide the width of the textArea by the width of one character and you get the amount of max characters per line.

```
double widthPerChar = fontMetrics.computeStringWidth("A");
double maxCharsPerLine = textArea.getWidth() / widthPerChar;
```